# PDO: error handling

Tags: php, pdo

I am working with PDO in PHP.

Now I wonder if you could catch any global error and show.

With global I mean if any `$sql=$connect->prepare()` fails, then echo out

`"Something went wrong:" . the_error`

Or would you need to always do it invidually each $sql ?

Comment: You can extend PDO to achieve the behaviour you desire.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `PDO::errorInfo()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

That's about as global as youre going to get.

Answer (score 3):

You could always catch exceptions thrown by the PDO class.

```
try
{
    ...new PDO('odbc:SAMPLE', 'db2inst1',...
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo "Failed: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I don't think that PDO Object throws an exception in all error cases. At least it is not like that in the following code (no parameters provided): `$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = :username AND `password` = :password";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();`